# Django - Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using class based views, and when I try to use the "paginate_by = 6" with the "def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):", I get the following error:

```
AssertionError at /

Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.2
Exception Type:     AssertionError
Exception Value:    

Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 953, in _filter_or_exclude
Python Executable:  C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.9.1
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\env\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 29 May 2021 00:11:20 +0000
```

I'm trying to do the pagination for the filters result, like if no filters applied it should do the pagination for all Tasks.

I've only found solution that do not use the functions with the Paginator. I would like to know if it is possible to do with the class based view and how, I'm a little lost in this.

my views.py:

```
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = "tasks"
    template_name = "todo/tasks.html"
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(user=self.request.user)
        context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()
        context["projects"] = Project.objects.all()

        search_input = self.request.GET.get("search") or ""
        project_input = self.request.GET.get("project") or ""
        complete_input = self.request.GET.get("complete") or ""

        if search_input:
            context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(title__icontains=search_input)
            context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()

        context["search_input"] = search_input

        if project_input:
            context["project_selected"] = project_input
            context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(
                project__name__icontains=project_input
            )
            context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()

        if complete_input == "all":
            context["complete_selected"] = complete_input
            context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(user=self.request.user)
            context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()
        else:
            if complete_input:
                context["complete_selected"] = complete_input
                context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(
                    user=self.request.user, complete=True
                )
                context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=True).count()
            else:
                context["complete_selected"] = ""
                context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(
                    user=self.request.user, complete=False
                )

        return context
```

my models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(00, 00))
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["complete", "-date", "title"]
```

if needed I can add more information

Answer (score 0):

create a deep copy of context['tasks'] and apply slicing on the copy of object instead of the main object

Comment: Could you give me an example of how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround, where I apply the Pagination to the context["tasks"] and then I do a copy of the url to maintain the filtering on each page.

**views.py:**

```
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = Task
context_object_name = "tasks"
template_name = "myapp/list.html"


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(user=self.request.user)
    context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()
    context["projects"] = Project.objects.all()

    search_input = self.request.GET.get("search") or ""
    project_input = self.request.GET.get("project") or ""
    complete_input = self.request.GET.get("complete") or ""

    if search_input:
        context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(title__icontains=search_input)
        context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()

    context["search_input"] = search_input

    if project_input:
        context["project_selected"] = project_input
        context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(
            project__name__icontains=project_input
        )
        context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()

    if complete_input == "all":
        context["complete_selected"] = complete_input
        context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(user=self.request.user)
        context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()
    else:
        if complete_input:
            context["complete_selected"] = complete_input
            context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(
                user=self.request.user, complete=True
            )
            context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=True).count()
        else:
            context["complete_selected"] = ""
            context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(
                user=self.request.user, complete=False
            )

    # Pagination
    paginated_tasks = Paginator(context["tasks"], 6)
    page_number = self.request.GET.get("page")
    task_page_obj = paginated_tasks.get_page(page_number)

    context["task_page_obj"] = task_page_obj

    get_copy = self.request.GET.copy()
    if get_copy.get("page"):
        get_copy.pop("page")
    context["get_copy"] = get_copy

    return context
```

**list.html:**

```
...
{% for task in task_page_obj %}
{% empty %}
<p>No tasks to show...</p>
{% endfor %}
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if task_page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1&{{ get_copy.urlencode }}">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ task_page_obj.previous_page_number }}&{{ get_copy.urlencode }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ task_page_obj.number }} of {{ task_page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if task_page_obj.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ task_page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ get_copy.urlencode }}">next</a>
        <a href="?page={{ task_page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}&{{ get_copy.urlencode }}">last &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should filter your queryset in the function below and it will override the default one:

`def get_queryset(self): return '<your query>'`

the error occur because you try to change an unevaluated queryset after you filtered it.
and now you can use `paginate_by = n` you shouldn't get any error.